# If you can combine 3+ arbitrarily sized integers and still be able to deconstruct it back

Tags: parsing, hash, integer

Say you have 3 integers:

```
13105
705016
13
```

I'm wondering if you could combine these into one integer *in any way*, so that you can still get back to the original 3 integers.

```js
var startingSet = [ 13105, 705016, 13 ]
var combined = combineIntoOneInteger(startingSet)
// 15158958589285958925895292589 perhaps, I have no idea.
var originalIntegers = deconstructInteger(combined, 3) 
// [ 13105, 705016, 13 ]

function combineIntoOneInteger(integers) {
  // some sort of hashing-like function...
}

function deconstructInteger(integer, arraySize) {
  // perhaps pass it some other parameters 
  // like how many to deconstruct to, or other params.
}
```

It doesn't need to technically be an "integer". It is just a string using only the integer characters, though perhaps I might want to use the hex characters instead. But I ask in terms of integers because underneath I do have integers of a bounded size that will be used to construct the combined object.

Some other notes....

- The combined value should be unique, so no matter what values you combine, you will always get a different result. That is, there are absolutely no conflicts. Or if that's not possible, perhaps an explanation why and a potential workaround.
- The mathematical "set" containing all possible outputs can be composed of different amounts of components. That is to say, you might have the output/combined set containing `[ 100, 200, 300, 400 ]` but the input set is these 4 arrays: `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 5 ], [ 91010, 132 ], [ 500, 600, 700 ] ]`. That is, the input arrays can be of wildly different lengths and wildly different sized integers.
- One way to accomplish this more generically is to just use a "separator" character, which makes it super easy. So it would be like `13105:705016:13`. But this is cheating, I want it to only use the characters in the integer set (or perhaps the hex set, or some other arbitrary set, but for this case just the integer set or hex).
- Another idea for a potential way to accomplish this is to somehow *hide* a separator in there by doing some hashing or permutation jiu jitsu so that `[ 13105, 705016, 13 ]` becomes some integer-looking thing like `95918155193915183`, where `155` and `5` are some separator like interpolator values based on the preceding input or some other tricks. A simpler approach to this would be like saying "anything following three zeroes `000` like `410001414` means it's a new integer. So basically `000` is a separator. But this specifically is ugly and brittle. Maybe it could get more tricky and work though, like "if the value is odd and followed by a multiple of 3 of itself, then it's a separator" sort of thing. But I can see that also having brittle edge cases.

But basically, given a set of integers `n` (of strings of integer characters), how to convert that into a single integer (or single integer-charactered string), and then convert it back into the original set of integers `n`.

Comment: Is the second number a typo for 9819518591591881?

Comment: I ask because the other two numbers you mentioned, 13 and 123931, are both prime. 9819518591591851 is not, but 98195185915918**8**1 is.

Comment: I'll update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are lots of ways to do this.

To start with, it's only necessary to have a reversible function which combines two values into one. (For it to be reversible, there must be another function which takes the output value and recreates the two input values.)

Let's call the function which combines two values `combine` and the reverse function `separate`. Then we have:

```
separate(combine(a, b)) == [a, b]
```

for any values `a` and `b`. That means that `combine(a, b) == combine(c, d)`
can only be true if both `a == c` and `b == d`; in other words, every pair of inputs produces a different output.

#### Encoding arbitrary vectors

Once we have that function, we can encode arbitrary-length input vectors. The simplest case is when we know in advance what the length of the vector is. For example, we could define:

```
combine3 = (a, b, c) => combine(combine(a, b), c)
combine4 = (a, b, c, d) => combine(combine(combine(a, b), c), d)
```

and so on. To reverse that computation, we only have to repeatedly call `separate` the correct number of times, each time keeping the second returned value. For example, if we previously had computed:

```
m = combine4(a, b, c, d)
```

we could get the four input values back as follows:

```
c3, d = separate(m)
c2, c = separate(c3)
a, b  = separate(c2)
```

But your question asks for a way to combine an arbitrary number of values. To do that, we just need to do one final `combine`, which mixes in the number of values. That lets us get the original vector back out: first, we call `separate` to get the value count back out, and then we call separate enough times to extract each successive input value.

```
combine_n = v => combine(v.reduce(combine), v.length)
function separate_n(m) {
  let [r, n] = separate(m)
  let a = Array(n)
  for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) [r, a[i]] = separate(r);
  a[0] = r;
  return a;
}
```

Note that the above two functions do not work on the empty vector, which should code to 0. Adding the correct checks for this case is left as an exercise. Also note the warning towards the bottom of this answer, about integer overflow.

---

#### A simple combine function: diagonalization

With that done, let's look at how to implement `combine`. There are actually many solutions, but one pretty simple one is to use the diagonalization function:

```
 diag(a, b) = (a + b)(a + b + 1)
              ------------------ + a
                        2
```

This basically assigns positions in the infinite square by tracing successive diagonals:

```
        <-- b -->
    0  1  3  6 10 15 21 ...
 ^  2  4  7 11 16 22 ...
 |  5  8 12 17 23 ...
 a  9 13 18 24 ...
 | 14 19 25 ...
 v 20 26 ...
   27 ...
```

(In an earlier version of this answer, I had reversed `a` and `b`, but this version seems to have slightly more intuitive output values.)

Note that the top row, where `a == 0`, is exactly the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which is not surprising because the already enumerated positions are the top left triangle of the square.

To reverse the transformation, we start by solving the equation which defines the triangular numbers, `m = s(s + 1)/2`, which is the same as

```
0 = s² + s - 2m
```

whose [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) can be found using the standard [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), resulting in:

```
s = floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * m)) / 2)
```

(`s` here is the original `a+b`; that is, the index of the diagonal.)

I should explain the call to `floor` which snuck in there. `s` will only be precisely an integer on the top row of the square, where `a` is 0. But, of course, `a` will usually not be 0, and `m` will usually be a little more than the triangular number we're looking for, so when we solve for `s`, we'll get some fractional value. `Floor` just discards the fractional part, so the result is the diagonal index.

Now we just have to recover `a` and `b`, which is straight-forward:

```
a = m - combine(0, s)
b = s - a
```

So we now have the definitions of `combine` and `separate`:

```
let combine = (a, b) => (a + b) * (a + b + 1) / 2 + a

function separate(m) {
  let s = Math.floor((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * m)) / 2);
  let a = m - combine(0, s);
  let b = s - a;
  return [a, b];
}
```

One cool feature of this particular encoding is that every non-negative integer corresponds to a distinct vector. Many other encoding schemes do not have this property; the possible return values of `combine_n` are a subset of the set of non-negative integers.

---

#### Example encodings

For reference, here are the first 30 encoded values, and the vectors they represent:

```
> for (let i = 1; i <= 30; ++i) console.log(i, separate_n(i));
 1 [ 0 ]
 2 [ 1 ]
 3 [ 0, 0 ]
 4 [ 1 ]
 5 [ 2 ]
 6 [ 0, 0, 0 ]
 7 [ 0, 1 ]
 8 [ 2 ]
 9 [ 3 ]
10 [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
11 [ 0, 0, 1 ]
12 [ 1, 0 ]
13 [ 3 ]
14 [ 4 ]
15 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
16 [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
17 [ 0, 1, 0 ]
18 [ 0, 2 ]
19 [ 4 ]
20 [ 5 ]
21 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
22 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
23 [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
24 [ 0, 0, 2 ]
25 [ 1, 1 ]
26 [ 5 ]
27 [ 6 ]
28 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
29 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
30 [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
```

#### Warning!

Observe that all of the unencoded values are pretty small. The encoded values is similar in size to the concatenation of all the input values, and so it does grow pretty rapidly; you have to be careful to not exceed Javascript's limit on exact integer computation. Once the encoded value exceeds this limit (2<sup>53</sup>) it will no longer be possible to reverse the encoding. If your input vectors are long and/or the encoded values are large, you'll need to find some kind of bignum support in order to do precise integer computations.

---

#### Alternative combine functions

Another possible implementation of `combine` is:

```
let combine = (a, b) => 2**a * 3**b
```

In fact, using powers of primes, we could dispense with the `combine_n` sequence, and just produce the combination directly:

`combine(a, b, c, d, e,...) = 2a 3b 5c 7d 11e`...

(That assumes that the encoded values are strictly positive; if they could be 0, we'd have no way of knowing how long the sequence was because the encoded value does not distinguish between a vector and the same vector with a 0 appended. But that's not a big issue, because if we needed to deal with 0s, we would just add one to all used exponents:

`combine(a, b, c, d, e,...) = 2a+1 3b+1 5c+1 7d+1 11e+1`...

That is certainly correct and its very elegant in a theoretical sense. It's the solution which you will find in theoretical CS textbooks because it is much easier to prove uniqueness and reversibility. However, in the real world it is really not practical. Reversing the combination depends on finding the prime factors of the encoded value, and the encoded values are truly enormous, well out of the range of easily representable numbers.

Another possibility is precisely the one you mention in the question: simply put a separator between successive values. One simple way to do this is to rewrite the values to encode in base 9 (or base 15) and then increment all the digit values, so that the digit 0 is not present in any encoded value. Then we can put 0s between the encoded values and read the result in base 10 (or base 16).

Neither of these solutions has the property that every non-negative integer is the encoding of some vector. (The second one *almost* has that property, and it's a useful exercise to figure out which integers are not possible encodings, and then fix the encoding algorithm to avoid that problem.)

Comment: Would be helpful if you could clarify the parentheses here `D(a, b) = (a + b)(a + b + 1)/2 + b`, wondering if you mean `D(a, b) = ((a + b) * (a + b + 1)) / (2 + b)`

Comment: Also, maybe you could show how to solve the quadratic equation, I am a bit off on where to implement it. Here is what I have so far. https://jsfiddle.net/eub546xy/

Comment: @lance: No, I meant usual arithmetic precedence where division has precedence over addition. I don't have much time today but I added a quick JS of diag and undiag to the answer. Hopefully you can figure out the other ones. Note that `diag` just computes the (a+b) triangular number and then adds b to that. See the diagram in the answer and wikipedia or some such about triangular numbers.

Comment: @lance: also, watch out for integer overflow. JS integer arithmetic is only precise up to 2**53, and the algorithm demands precision. If your numbers are big, you'll need bignum computations.

Comment: Ok thank you. Not sure really where to begin in solving the quadratic equation, hopefully you get the chance because this seems like a great solution. Wondering if this is it https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/blob/master/src/core/quadratic.js. Or perhaps [this](https://github.com/hnakamur/solve-quadratic-equation.js/blob/master/index.js) or [this](https://github.com/nicolewhite/algebra.js/blob/8c74b87dca81a7ea74a47e08bc5a0838805124e0/src/equations.js#L89), not sure.

Comment: @LancePollard: OK, I rewrote the answer to hopefully explain the mathematics with a bit more precision. (It's still mathematics, though.) And I added actual working code to illustrate the algorithm. You might want to play with the functions in a debugger rather than just copy-and-paste the code; if your numbers are as large as the example at the beginning of your question, you will definitely need to do something to avoid the problem in the section labelled "Warning!". (Using Python instead of Javascript would be one possible something.)

Comment: Oh wow this is so excellent, so helpful and clear. Thank you so much for the update!!!